# Use key to generate its corresponding value in a javascript object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build an object, that takes in any value (preferrably an int) as the key, which generates the value for the key using a function, that has a dictionary for mapping out each individual digit to a digit of another language. Basically, I am passing a number in English as the key, and want to retrieve it's corresponding value of a different language.

For example, let there be an object numbers, whose only key will be dynamic, and that key will be transformed using a function to generate the value for that key in the object.

```
numbers = {
    [number]: convertNumber(number)
}


const convertNumber = (number) => {
     let dict = {
        1: '١',
        2: '٢',
        3: '٣',
        4: '٤',
        5: '٥',
        6: '٦',
        7: '٧',
        8: '٨',
        9: '٩'
    }
    let newNumber = '';
    number.toString().forEach(digit => {
        newNumber = newNumber+dict[digit];
    });
    return newNumber;
}
```

Expected Output: numbers[1234] = '١٢٣٤';

But this code does not work, and I searched online for variable key names but did not find a way to be able to use a dynamic key value to be able to transform it and obtain a different number as the value to it's key. Is there a way to accomplish this using ES6?

***EDIT 1: ***
The function is not the issue here, I had a few errors but would have definitely been able to fix it by myself, I want to be able to retrieve a value from an object based on the key itself.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `map`? There is no `return` inside of it. And whrere is your array to use `map`?

Comment: And since when is `map` a method of _strings_?

Comment: My bad, I wanted a way to loop through the string to generate a new number. I have modified it with `forEach()`.

Comment: @Tribunal: Strings don't have a `forEach` method either.

Comment: You can't use `forEach` either

Comment: Are zeroes allowed in the number/string?

Comment: I see, I might have to use a traditional for loop to iterate through each character. But that's not the main point, I want to be able to use a dynamic key and use the key to generate it's corresponding value in the object. The `[number]=func(number)` approach is not working.

Comment: @Tribunal Why don't you just use the function? Why do you need the object with that functionality?

Comment: Because I am storing key-value pairs for translating strings into another language. But for numbers, I want to be able to put in any number as a key and be able to convert it into different language so I can generalize the translation to translate any number I want to. This is why I want to pass it through the numbers object, which is inside a larger object.

Comment: to use strings as key you have to create an object, you can't use arrays to use text as keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would recommend to set `dict` outside your function:

```
const dict = {
    1: "١",
    2: "٢",
    3: "٣",
    4: "٤",
    5: "٥",
    6: "٦",
    7: "٧",
    8: "٨",
    9: "٩"
  }
```

Then, as already has been told, you should `split` your string into characters to get an array of them, and then you can loop through that array. After that you should gather all of results to a string with `join`. And a function is as simple as next:

```
const convertNumber = number => {
    return number.toString().split("").map(digit => dict[digit]).join('');
};
```

Finally, I would recommend to use `regular expressions` to check if `number` is what it should be.

```js
const dict = {
        1: "١",
        2: "٢",
        3: "٣",
        4: "٤",
        5: "٥",
        6: "٦",
        7: "٧",
        8: "٨",
        9: "٩"
      }
      
const convertNumber = number => {
        return number.toString().split("").map(digit => dict[digit]).join('');
    };

const someNumbers = [123, 345, 334, 885];

const getNumberObject = arr => {
    return arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        acc[cur] = convertNumber(cur)
        return acc;
    }, {})
}

const numbers = getNumberObject(someNumbers)

console.log(numbers)
```

Comment: How do I use this function to generate a value from the key passed? While getting the value of numbers[1234], I want the key to be 1234 (dynamic value passed down) and the value to be it's transformed value. (Obtained from dict using the convertNumber() function you have defined).

Comment: `123: convertNumber(123)` still has 123 as a static value. How do I get a dynamic value, which is passed as the key to this object that I can then pass in the convertNumber() function?

Comment: `numbers[123] = convertNumber(123)` . And instead of `[123]` can be any variable `[anyVar]`

Comment: `const someNumbers = [123, 345, 334, 885];` is still static, with those 4 numbers. I want to have an object that takes in *any* key and returns it's value translated with convertNumber() function. The main purpose for this is that while there are fixed static string translations for words, like translation['word'] = 'translatedWord', for numbers, translation.numbers[*any number*] = translatedNumber, which will be done using convertNumber() function. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You don't need an `object`, you need a `function`. You can't return object's value if there is no related `key`. Dynamically you can only `assign` `key-value` pair for object.

Comment: So there is no way to retrieve the key being asked for and generate a value for that key based on the requested key? Because this translation plugin translates fixed strings based on key-value pairs in an object. I don't want to list all possible numbers being using in the website as keys.

Comment: Again - if there is no property of object then there is no value for that property. You should first `set` the value for that `key` and then get that. But it doesn't make sense since you can just return the value without using object with `key: value`.

Answer (score 1):

You were not far from having something that works, however, you tried to map in a `String` which does not work.

To still be able to use map you can use `split` which will gives you an  array of characters (ex: `foo` => `['f','o','o']`) that you can use as you like. Then, to get a string back, you can use the `join` method on `Array` and you'll get your final value.

```
const convertNumber = number => {
  let dict = {
    1: "١",
    2: "٢",
    3: "٣",
    4: "٤",
    5: "٥",
    6: "٦",
    7: "٧",
    8: "٨",
    9: "٩"
  };
  const newNumber = number
    .toString()
    .split("")
    .map(digit => {
      return dict[digit];
    }).join('');
  return newNumber;
};
```

[working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-mendel-z7puy)

Comment: If you explain what the OP did wrong and how/why your code works your answer will be much more helpful.

Comment: What about the main object? How do I accept a dynamic key and use the key to generate it's value?

Comment: `digit` is a dynamic key here. It could be anything (ex: `dict[digit + 1]` or `dict[digit + "_suffix"]` -- assuming it exists in `dict` ).

Comment: In `numbers = {
    [number]: convertNumber(number)
}` where does number come from ?

Comment: It's not exactly a variable, I want it to be any string we pass as the key. 
For example, numbers[10] will have key as 10, and value as  '١٢٣٤'.

Comment: Then, as I understand, you actually want a function which does that `number => ( { [number]: convertNumber(number)})`

Comment: Yes, correct. convertNumber() is a pretty simple function, that as the answers have suggested, can be written in one line. But that's not my main concern.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is you're not splitting your number string. 
If you just do `number.toString()`, it will be again a single string. So you need to split that string into individual digits and then check inside your dictionary.
To split the string you can use `number.toString().split('')`.

Please find working code below:

```js
let convertNumber = (number) => {
  let dict = {
    1: '١',
    2: '٢',
    3: '٣',
    4: '٤',
    5: '٥',
    6: '٦',
    7: '٧',
    8: '٨',
    9: '٩'
  }
  let newNumber = '';
  number.toString().split('').forEach(digit => {
    newNumber = newNumber + dict[digit];
  });
  return newNumber;
}

console.log(convertNumber(1234))
```

Also, you can't make newNumber variable as const, because you're assigning a value to that variable.

Comment: You can create a snippet on SO, [`How to create a running snippet on so`](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)